# Storing bools in SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite

In my table schema:

```
... disabled BOOLEAN, ...
```

When connecting to db:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(f, detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
sqlite3.register_converter("BOOLEAN", myfunc)
```

I insert a record like so:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (disabled, ...) VALUES (:disabled, ...)
```

Along with a parameter dict containing disabled: False.

When I read that record back, myfunc is called to convert the BOOLEAN type:

```
def myfunc(x):
    print x, type(x)
```

Result: `0, <type 'str'>`  (which of course evaluates as True when I want False)

I want bools stored as 1 byte INTEGER, I simply want to convert them to Python bool when reading records (other parts of code expect bools not ints). Is SQLite storing them as strings, or converting them to strings before calling myfunc? Why?

P.S. - I tried using `sqlite3.register_adapter(bool, int)`, to no avail.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting back a string but converting them to in and then to bool should be a workaround for now.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You want to use a combination of `register_adapter` and `register_converter` for the two directions:

```
sqlite3.register_adapter(bool, int)
sqlite3.register_converter("BOOLEAN", lambda v: bool(int(v)))
```

SQLite uses a [dynamic type system](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) but for custom types it has no way of knowing for certain if `0` is a string or an integer, so you get a string back here.

Alternatively, use:

```
sqlite3.register_converter("BOOLEAN", lambda v: v != '0')
```

which is a lot more flexible and robust when it comes to legacy data, but perhaps you *want* an exception to be raised.

Demo:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
>>> sqlite3.register_adapter(bool, int)
>>> sqlite3.register_converter("BOOLEAN", lambda v: bool(int(v)))
>>> db.execute('CREATE TABLE foo (bar BOOLEAN)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a17a340>
>>> db.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)', (True,))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a17a3b0>
>>> db.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?)', (False,))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x10a17a340>
>>> for row in db.execute('SELECT * FROM foo'):
...     print row
... 
(True,)
(False,)
```

Answer (score 2):

`sqlite3` doesn't have a `boolean` type - just store your field as an `integer` instead:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> db.execute('create table test (col1 integer)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x3737880>
>>> db.execute('insert into test values (?)', (1,))
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x3737960>
>>> print list(db.execute('select * from test'))
[(1,)]
```

A custom converter type takes the string representation of a stored column, and then you're expected to use that to create a new type from it...

If you did something like:

```
db = sqlite3.connect(':memory:', detect_types=sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES)
def myfunc(col):
    val = int(col) == 1
    print val, type(val)
    return val

sqlite3.register_converter('boolean', myfunc)

db.execute('create table blah (something boolean)')
db.executemany('insert into blah values (?)', [(True,), (False,)])
list(db.execute('select * from blah'))
```

You'll get a `bool` returned, which is what I think you want - however, you will need to make sure to handle exceptions, otherwise they get silently suppressed...

Comment: That is what the OP is trying to address; you can adapt types.

Comment: I know I can convert the string to an integer. My question is why it's giving me a string instead of an integer to begin with.